# Deploy 2 existing container in the same docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, visual-studio-2022

I have 2 container, 1 DB container and the Microservice container that uses the DB container for simple https requests.

I developed the Microservice in visual studio 2022 and I create the second container by the docker hub of microsoft sql server.

Inside my microservice project i create the docker-compose file to deploy the service container, but how can I deploy the 2 container togheter, like if they were in the same docker-compose file?

Comment: Can you edit the `docker-compose.yml` file and put both containers there?  Remember that containers are intrinsically kind of temporary, so recording a reproducible way to restart them is important – you should be on reasonably solid ground just deleting your existing unmanaged container.

Comment: okay, but i rly dont know how to do that.
Cuz for the microservice container I have his docker file , but for the database sql I have not a dockerfile because I created it by using the standard microsoft sql server.

And after creating the db I had to edit all the db with tables ecc.
Can you make/link an example of deploy a service container and a db in the same file, im kinda new to this topic sry...

Comment: I used this docker hub to create the db https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server

Comment: [Get started with Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/) in the Docker documentation has a Python/Redis example that you could probably adapt to your needs.

Comment: last question, is possible to use k8s on visual studio?

Comment: Ye but i cant create a dockerfile for the db, cuz i used the container in the link that i sayd